# How to send different strings to different hosts depending on the file that was commited. (gitlab ci/cd)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm absolutely new to all this ci/cd thing and its documentation is too extensive. So i'd like to apologize in advance if there is too easy question.
I have gitlab repo with many configs for different services i.e:

```
project_folder
--global_conf.json 
--service1
----config_folder
------....
--service2
----config_folder
------....
--service3
----config_folder
------....
```

I'd like to know what should I do (just general plan and some key words to search documentation more precisely already would be fine) to send to hosts [host1:port, host2:port, host3:port] different strings with commands "check {service_name} for changes" or "check {global_config} for changes" e.t.c, depending on the file that was committed.

I already have my service on each host that could perform different operations for different task's strings, so I need just send them that task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll propably end up using "only: changes" as explained [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges).

Something like this should fit:

```yaml
stages:
 - trigger

service1:
 stage: trigger
 script:
   - curl http://host1:port1
 only:
  changes:
    - service1/*

service2:
 stage: trigger
 script:
   - curl http://host2:port2
 only:
  changes:
    - service2/*
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try. Someday I will have to deal with all the documentation, but now is a bit of a wrong time.